# Distribution of the time for the first ocurrence in a Poisson Process given the number of events

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let N(t) a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$ where ocurrences are type I with probability $p$. Given that $N(t_0) = n$, what is the distribution of the waiting time for the first arrival of type I in the interval.

What I tried to do is to separate it in two processes, $N_1(t)$ of rate $\lambda p$ and $N_2(t)$ of rate $\lambda (1-p)$, so I did:

$$P(T_1 \le t | N_1(t_0) + N_2(t_0) = n) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(T_1 \le t | N_1(t_0) = n - i) P(N_2(t_0) = i)$$

Now I know that given $N_1(t_0) = n - i$, the distribution of the arrival times for $N_1$ are the same as the order statistics of $n-i$ uniform random variables. So in this case the conditional distribution of $T_1$ would be a Beta distribution or something like that.

However the beta distribution is not mentioned in my book before this question, so I think I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the waiting time for the first arrival will be *Exponential*. It follows from the principal of *count-time duality*.

$N(t)$ is a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda$ where $N(t)$ is the number of occurrences at or before time $t$. Let the waiting time for the first occurrence ($T_1$) is greater than $t$. This means that there are no occurrences from time $0$ to $t$, making $N(t)=0$. This makes the event $T_1 > t$ and $N(t)=0$ same [called as *count-time duality* and connects a continuous ($T_1$) and discrete ($N(t)$) RV].

So, we have $P(T_1 > t) = P(N(t) = 0) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t (\lambda t)^0}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda t}$ [as $N(t)$ is a Poisson Process]. $P(T_1 \leq t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$, making $T_1 \sim Expo(\lambda)$.

Hence, the time until the first arrival in a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$ has an Exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Time of the first arrival in Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ is exponential random variable $\sim Exp(\lambda)$. It is easy to prove
$$P(T_1>t)=P(\text{no arrivals in }(0,t])=e^{-\lambda t}$$ so the CDF is
$$
\begin{align}
 F_{T_1}(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
1-e^{-\lambda t} & \quad t>0 \\
& \quad \\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}$$
In your case, you have Poisson process with rate $p\lambda$ (obtained after splitting the original Poisson process).

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am a bit afraid because I want this distribution given the number of general ocurrences, and I know there is a dependence $P(T_1 < t ) = 1 - exp(-p\lambda t) \neq P(T_1 < t | N(t) =0)$

Comment: @JoséC. Sorry, but I don't understand what are you trying to do. You need not conditition on $N(t)=0$. The problem is very straightforward, you need only basic understanding of properties of Poisson process.